# What is the best approach for ensuring data integrity when transferring sensor data over Bluetooth Sockets?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, data-integrity

I am currently working on a project that deals with transferring sensor data (as a double, eventually as a double array) between Android devices. I have everything set up but as I test the data accuracy, I tend to get faulty numbers, extra numbers, etc.

I'm new to sockets in general, bytes, etc, and not sure where to look for best practices on Android Bluetooth Sockets or data transfer or anything on this matter.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just bugs in your code?

Comment: I modified the byte buffer size amount and that fixed the numbers issue. But I don't understand why this is so. I don't understand int/double/float to byte transformations nor data integrity. I say these words because they're buzzwords but I truly don't know where to look for more information for what I'm specifically looking for. This is why I'm here. Guidance for the best approach for data integrity.